# Google reCaptcha V2 and reCaptcha invisible

Tags: security, recaptcha

I'm using Google's new reCaptcha Invisible for a login system im making and it's working well. Because the algorithms are unknown for both products its hard to tell which is more effective.

I was wondering if people thought it was still necessary to display the usual "I'm not a robot" captcha after 5 failed logins or just using the invisible reCaptcha for all login attempts is enough.

If both reCaptchas use the same algorithm then surely there is no benefit to displaying the additional "I'm not a robot" captcha form.